# In flutter, how can I create a cookie for the first time a user visit the site, and check if that cookie exists in all the following visits?

Tags: flutter, cookies

I intend to show an alert when a user first visits the site, but never show it for subsequent visits of the same user. In order to do this, I need to know how to create a cookie during the first visit, and check its values on later visits to decide whether to show the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cookie, you can use the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin. It store data to local storage and it's much better than using cookie. It supports every platform.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        child: Text('Increment Counter'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save user token to shared preferences after first visit, therefore when user there for the first time, a call to shared preferences end up with null.